# Issue occures after parsed json from postman

Tags: json, swift, swift3

My scenario is parsing json, and show that informations on table view. Although parsing json scusess, print test correctly on console, but I still can not add that infos to my item object I really want.

I tried many ways, but still confuse why I can not.

First, with func loadProductListInfo(), i get out the below json:

```
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "ERFSDSSD"
            },
            {
                "id": 13,
                "name": "Messi"
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "DonadoNi_O"
            },
        ],
        "next_index": 0
    }
}
```

In that function, I also call func loadItemInfo(id: Int, item: Item) to get Item details with json like below, and print out to test.

```
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "next_index": 0,
        "data": [
            {
                "product_name": "AABBCC",
                "brand_name": "EVELYNE",
                "code": "DDEERR",
                "retail_price": 434632,
                "import_price": null,
                "properties": [
                    {
                        "caption": "Type 1",
                        "value": "Coats"
                    }
                ],
                "inventory": [
                    {
                        "quantity": 4,
                        "store": "BBB",
                        "id": 15,
                        "booking": [
                            {
                                "booking_quantity": 4,
                                "booking_staff": "KKK"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "quantity": 98,
                        "store": "AAA",
                        "id": 13,
                        "booking": [
                            {
                                "booking_quantity": 5,
                                "booking_staff": "SSSS"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "quantity": 2,
                        "store": "CCC",
                        "id": 14,
                        "booking": [
                            {
                                "booking_quantity": 1,
                                "booking_staff": "NNNN"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "image": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The json parsing result seem correct, but problem is after call loadProductListInfo(), the result of this line `self.item = item` not working anymore.
Below is my code in Search view controller:

```
class SearchVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

    //outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!



    //variables
    var isSearching = false
    var products = [Product]()
    var item = Item()
    var items = [Item]()
    var product = Product()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done

        loadProductListInfo()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func loadProductListInfo() {
        let parameters = [
            "method": "get_list",
            "param": [
                "list_name": "brand",
                "keyword2": "k",
                "start_index": 0,
                "page_size": 100
            ]
            ] as [String : Any]

        let headers = [
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.11.0",
            "Accept": "*/*",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Postman-Token": "3792a1a9-c3eb-449d-9c5d-22ff15e77bbc,75a0a1e1-963c-4937-a4af-42e76b863870",
            "Host": "123.4xx.x.y",
            "cookie": "ci_session=i3j4o9q0n7bd1s6015jurlkr0bfn596d",
            "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
            "content-length": "160",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "cache-control": "no-cache"
        ]

        do {
            let postData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://xxx.xxx.x.x/xxx/api/")! as URL,
                                              cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                              timeoutInterval: 10.0)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
            request.httpBody = postData as Data

            let session = URLSession.shared
            let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil) {
                    print("Error get jsonData: \(error)")
                } else {
                    let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                    print("Đây là httpResponse cua Get List Box: \(httpResponse)")
                    do {
                        if let convertedJsonDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                            print(convertedJsonDict)

                            if let result = convertedJsonDict["result"] as? [String:Any] {
                                print("Result day ne: \(result)")
                                if let dataArr: NSArray = result["data"] as? NSArray {
                                    for x in dataArr {
                                        if let productInfo = x as? [String: Any] {
                                            guard let productId = productInfo["id"] as? Int else {return}
                                            guard let productName = productInfo["name"] as? String else {return}
                                            let productInstance = Product(id: productId, name: productName)
                                            self.products.append(productInstance)
                                            print("Day la product list: \(productInstance.id, productInstance.name)")

                                            /*
                                            print("Items Arr: \(self.items), \(self.items.count)")
                                            for x in self.items {
                                                print("Item ID in Arr: \(x.itemName)")
                                            }
                                             */
                                        }
                                    }
                                    print("Products list: \(self.products.count)")
                                    for eachProduct in self.products {
                                        self.loadItemInfo(id: eachProduct.id, item: self.item)
                                        //properies of selft.item is null here.
                                        self.items.append(self.item)
                                    }
                                    print("Items Arr length: \(self.items.count)")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch let err as NSError {
                        print("Co Error nay: \(err)")
                    }
                }
            })

            dataTask.resume()
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print("Có error: \(err)")
        }
    }

    func loadItemInfo(id: Int, item: Item) {

        let headers = [
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.11.0",
            "Accept": "*/*",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Postman-Token": "37f3517d-e849-48e4-af20-134b7cc61322,31f79da6-e3fa-49a1-991f-a20837e9179e",
            "Host": "xxx.xxx.x.x",
            "cookie": "ci_session=i3j4o9q0n7bd1s6015jurlkr0bfn596d",
            "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
            "content-length": "149",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "cache-control": "no-cache"
        ]
        let parameters = [
            "method": "get_itemDetails",
            "param": [
                "id": id,
                "brand_name1": "",
                "product_code1": "",
                "product_name1": ""
            ]
            ] as [String : Any]
        do {
        let postData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://xxx.xxx.x.x/xxx/api/")! as URL,
                                          cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                          timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        request.httpBody = postData as Data

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error)
            } else {
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                print("Get Item httpResponse la : \(httpResponse)")

                do {
                    if let JsonDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                        print("\(JsonDict)")
                        if let result = JsonDict["result"] as? [String:Any] {
                            print("Result Get Item day ne: \(result)")
                            if let dataArr: NSArray = result["data"] as? NSArray {
                                print("Vo duoc data array")

                                let testArr = dataArr[0] as! NSDictionary
                                item.id = id //gán lại id product cho itemId được input
                                guard let product_name = testArr["product_name"] as? String else {return}
                                    print("product_name: \(product_name)")
                                    item.itemName = product_name
                                guard let retail_price = testArr["retail_price"] as? Int else {return}
                                    print("retail_price: \(retail_price)")
                                    item.giaBanLe = retail_price
                                if let inVen:NSArray = testArr["inventory"] as? NSArray {
                                    print("Khai bao inVen la Arr: \(inVen)")
                                    let inventoryArr = inVen[0] as! NSDictionary
                                    print("inventoryArr.count: \(inventoryArr.count)")
                                    guard let quantity = inventoryArr["quantity"] as? Int else {return}
                                    print("quantity: \(quantity)")
                                    //phai get quantity tai day
                                    item.soLuong = quantity
                                    guard let store = inventoryArr["store"] as? String else {return}
                                    print("store: \(store)")
                                    //phai get store nay
                                    if let bookingArr:NSArray = inventoryArr["booking"] as! NSArray, bookingArr.count > 0 {
                                        print("Khai bao bookingArr la Array")
                                        print(bookingArr)
                                        for i in bookingArr {
                                            if let bookingArrContent = i as? [String: Any] {

                                                guard let booking_quantity = bookingArrContent["booking_quantity"] as? Int else {return}
                                                print("booking_quantity: \(booking_quantity)")
                                                //phai get booking_quantity
                                                item.booking = booking_quantity
                                                guard let booking_staff = bookingArrContent["booking_staff"] as? String else {return}
                                                print("booking_staff: \(booking_staff)")
                                                //phai get booking_staff
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }else {
                                        var booking_quantity = 0
                                        var booking_staff = ""
                                        print("booking_quantity: \(booking_quantity)")
                                        //phai get booking_quantity
                                        item.booking = booking_quantity
                                        print("booking_staff: \(booking_staff)")
                                        //phai get booking_staff
                                    }

                                    guard let image = testArr["image"] as? String else {return}
                                    print("image: \(image)")
                                    item.imgURL = image
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    /*
                    self.item = item
                    print("self.item Name: \(self.item.itemName)")
                    print("self.item Booking Quantity: \(self.item.booking)")
                    print("self.item Img: \(self.item.imgURL)")
                    print("self.item ID: \(self.item.id)")
                     */
                } catch let err as NSError {
                    print("Co Error nay: \(err)")
                }

                self.item = item
                print("self.item Name: \(self.item.itemName)")
                print("self.item Booking Quantity: \(self.item.booking)")
                print("self.item Img: \(self.item.imgURL)")
                print("self.item ID: \(self.item.id)")

            }
        })
        dataTask.resume()
            /*
            self.item = item
            print("self.item Name: \(self.item.itemName)")
            print("self.item Booking Quantity: \(self.item.booking)")
            print("self.item Img: \(self.item.imgURL)")
            print("self.item ID: \(self.item.id)")
            */
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print("Error roi :\(err)")
        }
        /*
        self.item = item
        print("self.item Name: \(self.item.itemName)")
        print("self.item Booking Quantity: \(self.item.booking)")
        print("self.item Img: \(self.item.imgURL)")
        print("self.item ID: \(self.item.id)")
         */
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as?  CustomCellVC {
            //cell.configureItemCell(item: item)
            item = items[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureItemCell(item: item)
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }

}
```

My item class:

```
class Item {

    var id: Int
    var itemName: String
    var soLuong: Int
    var giaBanLe: Int
    var imgURL: String
    var booking: Int

    init(id: Int = 0, itemName: String = "", soLuong: Int = 0, giaBanLe: Int = 0, imgURL: String = "", booking: Int = 0) {
        self.id = id
        self.itemName = itemName
        self.soLuong = soLuong
        self.giaBanLe = giaBanLe
        self.imgURL = imgURL
        self.booking = booking
    }
}
```

In this processing:

```
                                            for x in self.items {
                                                print("Item ID in Arr: \(x.itemName)")
                                            }
                                             */
                                        }
                                    }
                                    print("Products list: \(self.products.count)")
                                    for eachProduct in self.products {
                                        self.loadItemInfo(id: eachProduct.id, item: self.item)
                                        //properies of selft.item is null here.
                                        self.items.append(self.item)
                                    }
                                    print("Items Arr length: \(self.items.count)")
```

I got `products.count` = 13 (ex)
But when i count this line `print("self.item Name: \(self.item.itemName)")` ' s result is only: 6.
My expected: is 13 too. How should I modify to get that expected?
Please help me to store item' s properties and show on table view. Now my table view still blank, do not show anything, please point how to do that?
Thank you in advance. (Note: I modified some json values for not too long.)

Comment: You are encouraged to use `Decodable`. It's much easier to use and you can create the required structs [online](https://app.quicktype.io/?l=swift)

Comment: You are missing the asynchronous concept. After `task.resume()`, add `print("After resume")`. After `self.item = item`, add `print("Inside closure")`. The one that will be printed before is not the one you are thinking. Look for "Swift + Closure + Async", it's a basic and common "issue".

Comment: @Larme Following your advice, the test result is : `print("Products list: \(self.products.count)")` is excuted first, next is  `print("After resume")`,  consecutive excuted without printing parsing json result out. Only when all of the "After resume" strings are printed, the parsing json result will be printed. Please help me to fix that, and please point out how to assign `item` (input parameter of `func loadItemInfo`) to the global variable named `item` to use after func `loadItemInfo`.